# Force Https in Websphere 6.1

Tags: servlets, https, websphere, rad

I was wondering how i can force a user who has requested a page using Http to use the secure https version?

I am using Websphere 6.1 as my application server and Rad 7 as my development environment

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that you could do this within your application rather than in the server configuration would be to use a [Filter](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) (specified in your web.xml) to check if `ServletRequest.getScheme()` is "http" or "https", and re-direct the user to the appropriate URL (using `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(String url)`).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following entry in your web.xml and it will make sure all requests are converted to https

```
<!--********************************
   *** SSL Security Constraint  ***
   *****************************-->
   <security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>SSL</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <user-data-constraint>
           <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
       </user-data-constraint>
   </security-constraint>

<!--********************************* -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Websphere is not a complete http server. It does have 'Transport Chains', which act like an HTTP Server.

Normally you will put a HTTP server in front. IBM provides IHS (IBM HTTP Server) which is a lightly modified Apache HTTP Server. The HTTP Server is configured with the httpd.conf file. There you add redirects in such a way that request for http are redirected to https.

Maybe you can give some detailed information about your infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. I think using a Filter will achieve this. Here is a Filter I wrote for load balancing and port redirection but it should be easy to figure out how to edit it to fit your needs.

public class RequestWrapperFilter implements Filter {

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
        ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    String requestWrapperClassName = (String) (httpRequest
            .getAttribute(LoadBalancerRequestWrapper.class.getName()));

    String initiatingServerName = httpRequest.getServerName();

    if (requestWrapperClassName == null
            && initiatingServerName.equals(loadBalancerHostName)) {

        httpRequest = new LoadBalancerRequestWrapper(AuthenticationUtil
                .getHttpServletRequest(httpRequest));
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
}
```

}

```
/**
 * The custom implementation of the request wrapper. It simply overrides the
 * getScheme() and getServerPort() methods to perform the redirect
 * filtering.
 * 
 * 
 */
private static class LoadBalancerRequestWrapper extends
        HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    /**
     * Default Constructor. Simply declares the Wrapper as injected.
     * 
     * @param httpServletRequest
     *            the app-server HttpServletRequest.
     * 
     */
    public LoadBalancerRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        super(httpServletRequest);
    }

    /**
     * The overridden scheme.
     * 
     */
    public final String getScheme() {
        if (loadBalancerHttpScheme.equals(EMPTY_STRING)) {
            return super.getScheme();
        }

        return loadBalancerHttpScheme;
    }
}
```

}